# Exit from App without going back to any of previous activities/views Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble to exit from my app from the current activity/view (i.e, **Home**). My app starts with **Splash** > **Login** > **OTP** > **Home**.
I want to be able to navigate to and fro from **Splash** <> **Login** <> **OTP**. As soon as I reach **Home** and I press back, the app should exit. 
Below is an example of my situation

**Splash:**

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('Goto Login'),
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
    },
  ),
```

**Login:**

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('Goto OTP'),
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OTP()));
    },
  ),
```

**OTP:**

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('Goto Home'),
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    },
  ),
```

**Home:**

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('Goto Others'),
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Others()));
    },
  ),
```

AFAIK `Navigator.pushReplacement()` is some sort of solution here, I tried but it only skips the activity/view where it is implemented.

`SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')` with `WillPopScope()` works but it displays the previous activity/view (**OTP**) for a moment then exits the app, which doesn't look good.

`exit(0)` is not recommended.

So, any ideas for best practices and a simple approach for such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (_) => false);`
Delete all historical routes before jumping to home

Comment: Added this `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Home.id, (_) => false)` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can try using Navigator.pushReplacement() method in OTP screen, which goes to the Home page by disposing all previous routs and hence pressing back button in home page exists the app.

Comment: This will only skip OTP screen and display Login Screen if pressed back from Home, I tried it already.